# How can I remove %2F from my URL with htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I got this page:
/Storing/Users_Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FStoring%2Fdefault.aspx

this page get 404 error and i want redirect him to my main page.
so, this page
http://mydomain.com/Storing/Users_Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2FStoring%2Fdefault.aspx
to
http://mydomain.com

i think to do that by take those problem characters :%2F and just remove them and than i will redirect the page:
/Storing/Users_Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=Storingdefault.aspx
to my main page.

how can i do that? i know something about rewrite or something..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/Storing/Users_Login\.aspx\?ReturnUrl=\%2FStoring\%2Fdefault.aspx [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Make sure this is your very first rule.